# Service Account for Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform

On the [Google Cloud Authentication Overview](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/) page it states the following for cloud services:

> For almost all cases, whether you are developing locally or in a
>   production application, you should use service accounts, rather than
>   user accounts or API keys.

With this in mind, my question is when using the Google Maps Platform, seeing as it is a Google Cloud product, would it be necessary to setup a service account, or will an API key still suffice in these situations?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After some more investigation I found that the Google Maps Platform doesn't support service accounts at this time, you definitely still need an API key [as seen here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

Google does offer a premium plan that does allow for making requests with [a client ID](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/overview#client-id).