# Service Account for Google Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-cloud-platform, google-maps-api-3

Can I use service account for google places API?

Someone asked a similar question 3 years ago, is it still true?

[Service Account for Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54942344/service-account-for-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use a service account.

> Google Maps Platform products are secured from unauthorized use by
> restricting API calls to those that provide proper authentication
> credentials. These credentials are in the form of an **API key**.

Reference:

[Use API Keys with Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/get-api-key)